# WPF how to access a property through Template of a control (XAML only)

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, binding

I have a simple xaml example and I want to change CornerRadius property, which is set through ControlTemplate of Button.  I need a way to change it through Button.  One use case is:  I have 2 buttons, one sets to "BigRadius" and another one sets to "SmallRadius".  If I change the default one on Border, then both buttons will have the same CornerRadius.  Is there a way to do this in XAML only?

```
<Window x:Class="StyleDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border  CornerRadius="5"  BorderBrush="Blue" 
                                BorderThickness="5" 
                                Width="80"
                                Height="40"                               
                                x:Name="BaseBorder">
                          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Name="GridWithMarginStyle">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12"></Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <!--This button will have a big corner radius-->
        <Button Name="Ok" Content="Ok"></Button>

        <!--This button will have a small corner radius-->
        <Button Name="CancelBtn" Click="CancelBtn_Click">Cancel</Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need two styles for the Button to achieve what you are doing or create a Custom Button to implement CornerRadius as DependencyProperty, and bind it with CornerRadius of Border in ControlTemplate.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="LargeRadiusStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="SmallRadiusStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border CornerRadius="3" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer.  I bet it is going to work but there are other properties, for example BorderBrush or Background which I don't need to change.  In this approach, I need to repeat all the properties that I don't need to change in both places.  Is there another way to approach this (Other than use dependency property)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have against DPs. You need SOMETHING to tell the button whether you want the big radius or the small radius. WPF can't read your mind (yet) :). If you don't want a custom button class, then you can use an attached property.